What is the difference between destructuring and and just using properties in React
I have some problems regarding React code. Inside my App.jsx, I wrote the logic with and without the destructuring of an object I get from an  jsx tag:

<input
   name="fName"
   placeholder="First Name"
   onChange={handleChange}
   value={fullName.fName}
/>
<input
   name="lName"
   placeholder="Last Name"
   onChange={handleChange}
   value={fullName.lName}
/>


Here is the code with destructuring way:

function handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setFullName((preValue) => {
      if (name === "fName") {
        return {
          fName: value,
          lName: preValue.lName,
        };
      } else if (name === "lName") {
        return {
          fName: preValue.fName,
          lName: value,
        };
      }
    });
  }

While this is the code without destructuring way

function handleChange(event) {
    setFullName((preValue) => {
      if (event.target.name === "fName") {
        return {
          fName: event.target.value,
          lName: preValue.lName,
        };
      } else if (event.target.name === "lName") {
        return {
          fName: preValue.fName,
          lName: event.target.value,
        };
      }
    });
  }

Note that I tried to write the code with the same logic. However, while the former does work, in the latter way, my code doesn't work and starts to crash showing this error:
TypeError
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')
eval
/src/components/App.jsx:11:23
   8 | 
   9 | function handleChange(event) {
  10 |   setFullName((preValue) => {
> 11 |     if (event.target.name === "fName") {
     |                     ^
  12 |       return {
  13 |         fName: event.target.value,
  14 |         lName: preValue.lName,



I expect it to work even when I do not use the destructuring

In the first example, the values name and value are copied before setFullName is called. In the second example, the object event is accessed. You get different behavior, if the object is modified.

@jabaa …and in fact the event object is modified, as it bubbles up the DOM tree until reaching the top; before the component re-renders and the state updater function is called. I'm a bit surprised that event.target becomes null (not just event.currentTarget, which changes during bubbling), but this might as well be specific to React's synthetic events.

I think your issue is an issue with scope. Just get rid of the setFullName function declaration and just keep the body of the function.

@hippoman That's not a function declaration. That's a function call.

Seems you are using an older version of React and the event has been nullified and returned to the event pool. I believe this changed in React 17. Call event.persist() in the second implementation if you'd like the event object to hand around until the React state update is processed.

This has nothing to do with destructuring. It's only important, when you access the object.
In the first snippet, the values name and value are copied before setFullName is called. In the second example, the object event is accessed after setFullName is called. The object is mutable and you get different behavior, if the object is modified before its values are read.


const event = {
  target: {
    name: 'Name',
    value: 123
  }
}

function f1(event) {
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  g(() => { console.log(name, value); });
}

function f2(event) {
  g(() => { console.log(event.target.name, event.target.value); });
}

function g(f) {
  setTimeout(f, 10);
}

f1(event);
f2(event);
event.target.name = 'New name';
event.target.value = 321;



Example:
You can achieve the same behavior with and without desctructuring.


const event = {
  target: {
    name: 'Name',
    value: 123
  }
}

function f1(event) {
  g(() => { 
    const { name, value } = event.target; 
    console.log(name, value);
  });
}

function f2(event) {
  const name = event.target.name;
  const value = event.target.value;
  g(() => { console.log(name, value); });
}

function g(f) {
  setTimeout(f, 10);
}

f1(event);
f2(event);
event.target.name = 'New name';
event.target.value = 321;




I understand your example. However, I want to ask more, in my code, why it get the error of Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name'), although i continue to type in value in the input tag

Please don't ask follow up questions in comments. If you have a new question, post a new question.

@ThangThang The point is, if you got your question answered, you may accept it (there's button for that), or not. If you have a followup question that's to big to fit in the current question, just ask another question.
